# Mongo - Match where object key is variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo DB with the following object:

```
[
    {
        "link" : "xxxxx.jpg"
        "_id" : ObjectId("5501b1648ef0b4eccc41814e"),
        "processed" : {
            "320" : true,
            "480" : true,
            "540" : true,
            "720" : true,
            "800" : true,
            "1080" : true,
            "original" : false,
            "iPhone" : true
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to query where any of the processed values is false, but I cannot seem to figure out how to query where I do not know which key matches. Is this possible without looping through all documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a document schema like you've put in the original post, we can use Javascript to;

- Find all records
- Loop through `processed` object
- If *any* value equates to boolean `false`, add the `_id` to an array
- Print the `_id`'s that have a `false` value in `processed` object

**Query to run**

```
var arrDoc = [];
db.test.find().forEach(
    function anyFalse(doc) {
         for(key in doc.processed) {
            if(doc.processed.hasOwnProperty(key) && doc.processed[key] === false) {
                arrDoc.push(doc._id);
                break;
            }
         }
    });
print( arrDoc.join("\r\n") );
```

**Example document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5107de525ed6103609000016"),
    "link" : "xxxxx.jpg",
    "processed" : {
        "320" : true,
        "480" : true,
        "540" : true,
        "720" : true,
        "800" : true,
        "1080" : true,
        "original" : false,
        "iPhone" : true
    }
}
```

**Example output**

```
ObjectId("5107de525ed6103609000016")
```

**Further notes**

You can store this javascript function `anyFalse` into Mongo and call it when you need it. See [store javascript function on server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)

---

### Edit

As noted in the comments, you have an `images` array. This function will loop through all the `images` array to check child `processed` for false.

**Query to run**

```
var arrDoc = [];
db.test.find().forEach(
    function anyFalse(doc) {
         var len = doc.images.length;
         for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
             for(key in doc.images[i].processed) {
                if(doc.images[i].processed.hasOwnProperty(key) && doc.images[i].processed[key] === false) {
                    arrDoc.push(doc.images[i]._id);
                    break;
                }
             }
         }
    });
print( arrDoc.join("\r\n") );
```

**Example document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5534fe2f3614af9afd23310a"),
    "images" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5107de525ed6103609000016"),
            "link" : "xxxxx.jpg",
            "processed" : {
                "320" : true,
                "480" : true,
                "540" : true,
                "720" : true,
                "800" : true,
                "1080" : true,
                "original" : true,
                "iPhone" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5107de525ed6103609000017"),
            "link" : "xxxxx.jpg",
            "processed" : {
                "320" : true,
                "480" : true,
                "540" : true,
                "720" : true,
                "800" : true,
                "1080" : true,
                "original" : false,
                "iPhone" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks good, however the object here is in an array, how would you modify the code to take this into account?

For example, the array is called images and contains multiple of these image objects.

I attempted to modify `doc.processed` to `doc.images.0.processed` to work on the first image in each, but was thrown an error

Comment: Use the square brackets. `doc.images[0].processed`

Answer (score 3):

With MongoDB 3.4.4, use the aggregation framework to query the document. This is made possible with the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator which allows you to map the keys in the processed field to an array of key/value pairs. The list will be easy to filter and get the key(s) that matches whatever condition you have.

In the following example, the aggregation pipeline consists of an extra field which holds the key(s) that match the above condition of having a false value, so ideally it will be an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "notProcessed": { 
            "$map" : {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$processed" },
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$not": "$$el.v" }
                    }
                },
                "in": "$$this.k"
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

which yields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5501b1648ef0b4eccc41814e"),
    "link" : "xxxxx.jpg",
    "processed" : {
        "320" : true,
        "480" : true,
        "540" : true,
        "720" : true,
        "800" : true,
        "1080" : true,
        "original" : false,
        "iPhone" : true
    },
    "notProcessed" : [ 
        "original"
    ]
}
```

---

### Explanations

Starting with the nested expression

```
{
    "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$processed" },
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$not": "$$el.v" }
    }
}
```

the input to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator [`{ "$objectToArray": "$processed" }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#exp._S_objectToArray) will convert the keys in the `processed` key to this array:

```
[ 
    {
        "k" : "320",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "480",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "540",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "720",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "800",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "1080",
        "v" : true
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "original",
        "v" : false
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "iPhone",
        "v" : true
    }
]
```

and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) will filter the above array to have only the object elements whose `v` property is `NOT` `true`:

```
[ 
    {
        "k" : "original",
        "v" : false
    }
]
```

[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) will then return a mapped array with just the values

```
[ { "k" : "original", "v" : false } ] => [ "original" ]
```

so you end up with just

```
[ "original" ]
```

as a result.

---

With older MongoDB versions, it's going to be pretty difficult to issue queries against dynamic keys. Consider modifying your schema to follow this document model which is easier to query:

```
// this operation changes the schema
var processed = [];
db.collection.find().forEach( function(doc) {
     for(key in doc.processed) {
        if(doc.processed.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var item = { key: key, value: doc.processed[key] }
            processed.push(item);            
        }
     }
     doc.processed = processed;
     db.collection.save(doc);
});

// modified schema    

{ 
    "link": "xxxxx.jpg"
    "_id": ObjectId("5501b1648ef0b4eccc41814e"),
    "processed": [
         { "key": "320", "value": true },
         { "key": "480", "value": true },
         { "key": "540", "value": true },
         { "key": "720", "value": true },
         { "key": "800", "value": true },
         { "key": "1080", "value": true },
         { "key": "original", "value": false },
         { "key": "iPhone", "value": true }
    ]
}
```

Your find query will be simply

```
db.collection.find({"processed.value": false});
```

or use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to return the keys with `false` values as

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "link": 1,
        "notProcessed": { 
            "$map" : {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$processed",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$not": "$$el.v" }
                    }
                },
                "in": "$$this.k"
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative if OP can change all the schemas. If OP cannot, [javascript function may be the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29746604/3000179) (Is shameless referring allowed?)