# Update a given mongo field in unknown parents fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have a document structured like that :

```
datas: {
    foo: {
        ...
        keytoupdate: [...]
    },
    whatever: {
        ...
        keytoupdate: [...]
    },
    anystring: {
        ...
        keytoupdate: [...]
    },
    ...: {
        ...
        keytoupdate: [...]
    }
}
```

I know that :

- Each direct child property of the "datas" document has a "keytoupdate" field.
- The direct child properties of the "datas" document varies from case to case: not necessarily the same name, neither the same number.

I want to update each "keytoupdate" fields, no matter how many of them there are.

The question is: How can I do that ? Is there any magic operator like [$ that does the same job for Array](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) ?

Thank you !

Comment: A workaround would be to redesign the schema in such a way that the keys become part of the property values because it's pretty hard to issue queries against dynamic keys. You might want to see this [**SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745878/mongo-match-where-object-key-is-variable) for more details on how you can go about it

Comment: @chridam Unfortunatly I can't redesign the schema, it's embeded in a very big structure :s

Comment: This doesn't make sense - if you don't know the name of the key above `keytoupdate`, then you don't know what field you need to query/update. There's no `keytoupdate` field in the above document; there is only `key1.keytoupdate`, `key2.keytoupdate`, etc. Can you formulate your question so it is well-posed? What is the exact query and/or document transformation that you would like to do?

Comment: @wdberkeley Just did, check the update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question : **there is no way to do that, we can't play with dynamic keys, just forget about it** ! But there are 2 workarounds :

1. **The best solution**, as suggested by @chridam, is to redesign the schema to make an array of objects, where the keys are parts of the arrays, you can see [this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745878/mongo-match-where-object-key-is-variable)
2. If you can't, the other (but not good) solution is to make a request for each field that might be in your document, instead of trying to do this in one request. This is a very bad solution, especially if your document may have lots of fields, and you have to known which fields that could be in your documents. **This is a bad solution**, absolutely not optimized, but it has the merit of being simple to implement